# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt i} < 2 \sqrt n$ by induction - result doesn't match to wolfram alpha's result

Tags: inequality, induction, wolfram-alpha

According to wolfram alpha, this inequality isn't true for $n > 2$. My result says otherwise. Assuming that the inequality is true for $n+1$,
 $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt i} < 2  \sqrt {n+1}$
by adding $\frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}}$  to both sides of the original inequality, the following must be true 
$$ 2 \sqrt n + \frac{1}{\sqrt {n+1}} < 2 \sqrt{n+1}$$
the previous inequality is satisfied for $n\ge 0$. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: what is true is that the sum minus $2 \sqrt n$ approaches a limit, as $n$ gets larger. This limit is of modest size, might be positive, might be negative. I will check

Comment: Don't get were the induction step is in your reasoning.

Comment: You mean the "let n = k" statement?

Comment: @Nightgap I have tried the following - (prove sum 1/sqrt(j) j=1 to n < 2*sqrt(n) by induction assuming n>2)    , it seems that it can identify this query correctly judging by the "input interpretation" tab.

Comment: The sum is, in the limit, $2 \sqrt n - 1.46$

Comment: You would need to do something like... $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^{-1/2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{-1/2}+(n+1)^{-1/2}<2\sqrt{n}+1/\sqrt{n+1}<?2\sqrt{n+1}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $2\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}<2\sqrt{n+1}$ if and only if $2\sqrt{n(n+1)}<2(n+1)-1=2n+1$ if and only if $4n(n+1)<(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1$ if and only if $0<1$. Therefore assuming $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}<2\sqrt{n}$ gives $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}<2\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}<2\sqrt{n+1}$ exactly as you suggested.

Also note that the function $f(x):=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is strictly decreasing. Therefore $\sum_{i=1}^nf(i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}((i+1)-i)f(i+1)<\int_0^nf(x)dx=2\sqrt{n}$ gives another proof of the inequality in question.

The wolfram output is indeed really weird.